# Java 8 orElseThrow: why is compiler not complaining that method does not have a "throws"

Tags: java, exception

I have the following code:

```
public Trail getNewestTrail() {
    return trails.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Trail::getTimestamp)).orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);

}
```

I am not seeing any error without having getNewestTrail declared as throwing the exception -- why?

Answer (score 8):

[`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) extends from `java.lang.RuntimeException`, it is [uncheched exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html):

> Java programming language does not require methods to catch or to
>   specify unchecked exceptions (RuntimeException, Error, and their
>   subclasses)

you only need specify checked exception in method signature.

Comment: Given that without the orElseThrows I get a compile error which says I should use Optional instead of Trail, should I add the throws to the method signature anyway?

Comment: @releseabe If you expect an exceptio be thrown when there is non max element found, you can use `orElseThrow` and need not use `throws` in the signature.

Comment: Would we not want the caller to know about the potential of the exception?

Comment: @releseabe If you want the caller notice that, you need throw a checked exception. Then you have to use throws in the signature. Otherwise the complier will complain.

Comment: I am puzzled that I have to add the orElseThrows and yet it is an unchecked exception.

Comment: @releseabe It's no necessary to use orElseThrows clause. You can just let this method return `Optional<Trail>` and let the caller check if the max element exists.

Answer (score 1):

`NoSuchElementException` is a `RuntimeException` and they need not be handled at compile time.

Just to check, replace `NoSuchElementException` with `Exception` and it will start giving you a compilation failure.